# CSS transform on SVG Elements IE9+

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, css-transforms

Having a SVG Path:

```
<path class='st8' d='M73.4,11.3c-6.3,0-6.4,3.6-6.4,3.6v18c0,0,0.6,3.3,6.4,3.3c5.8,0,6.6-3.3,6.6-3.3v-18 C80,14.9,79.7,11.3,73.4,11.3z M75,31.3c0,0-0.3,1.2-1.6,1.2c-1.3,0-1.4-1.2-1.4-1.2V16.6c0,0,0.3-1.3,1.5-1.3s1.5,1.3,1.5,1.3V31.3 z'/>
```

I have tried to transform it from CSS instead of declaring the `transform` attribute from the element tag.

This process works fine from webkit and firefox, however when testing on IE9 or 10 [nothing happens](http://jsfiddle.net/k3yb6/6/).

```
<svg>
    <style>
        .st8 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* works on chrome and Safari */
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* works on firefox */
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* doesn't work on IE */
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
    <style>
    <path class='st8' d='M73.4,11.3c-6.3,0-6.4,3.6-6.4,3.6v18c0,0,0.6,3.3,6.4,3.3c5.8,0,6.6-3.3,6.6-3.3v-18 C80,14.9,79.7,11.3,73.4,11.3z M75,31.3c0,0-0.3,1.2-1.6,1.2c-1.3,0-1.4-1.2-1.4-1.2V16.6c0,0,0.3-1.3,1.5-1.3s1.5,1.3,1.5,1.3V31.3 z'/>
</svg>
```

I have tried to search the web for any place mentioning that css transform indeed doesn't work on IE, however I couldn't find it. Hence my question, is it indeed not possible to use css transform on IE? Is there any workaround besides having to strictly use the `transform` attribute in the element tag?

Answer (score 22):

IE11 supports the transform attribute in SVG even though it doesn't recognize the CSS style.

Fortunately, you can simply set the attribute to match the style using JavaScript:

```js
var g = document.querySelector('.st8'),
    transform = getComputedStyle(g).getPropertyValue('transform');
    
g.setAttribute('transform', transform);
```

```css
.st8 {
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* doesn't work on IE */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path class='st8' d='M73.4,11.3c-6.3,0-6.4,3.6-6.4,3.6v18c0,0,0.6,3.3,6.4,3.3c5.8,0,6.6-3.3,6.6-3.3v-18 C80,14.9,79.7,11.3,73.4,11.3z M75,31.3c0,0-0.3,1.2-1.6,1.2c-1.3,0-1.4-1.2-1.4-1.2V16.6c0,0,0.3-1.3,1.5-1.3s1.5,1.3,1.5,1.3V31.3 z'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hmm, it works in my IE9 emulator, but I don't have an IE9 computer to test it with.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: No problems, I tested it on VirtualBox with iso from www.modern.ie, its the safest option i think. Also I found out you just cant tranform svg images in IE9, so I used a png.

Answer (score 17):

Although IE9+ support CSS3 transforms, they don't support them on SVG and to the best on my knowledge it can't be done in CSS.

source:
caniuse under known issues for CSS3 Transforms
http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d