# CSS Animation not working in IE/Edge

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, microsoft-edge, css-transforms

How can this thing work in IE/Edge? i don't understand why it doesn't.

When i add a class to an element its border becomes dashed and starts rotating.

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {
  $(".bg")[0].classList.toggle("rotate");
})
```

```css
@keyframes PDFgenerating {
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.bg circle {
  fill:white;
  stroke: blue;
}
.bg circle {
  -moz-transition : stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -o-transition  : stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  transition   : stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  stroke-dasharray : 290 !important;
}

.bg.rotate circle {
  -moz-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -o-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -moz-animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite reverse;
  -o-animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite reverse;
  -webkit-animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite reverse;
  animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite reverse;
  stroke-dasharray: 28 !important;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myIcon" style = "width:100px"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" focusable="false"><g class="bg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45.56" style="stroke-width:4.44;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0"></circle></g><g class="fg" transform="translate(50,50) scale(0.5) translate(-50,-50)"><g transform="matrix(0.19920319,0,0,0.19920319,2.5095651e-4,-1.38e-6)"> <g> <path d="m 478.482,448.601 -101.6,-101.599 c 8.089,-15.262 12.339,-32.29 12.339,-49.717 0,-35.689 -18.182,-69.164 -47.804,-88.743 V 92.53 c 0,-2.652 -1.054,-5.196 -2.929,-7.071 L 255.959,2.929 C 254.083,1.054 251.54,0 248.888,0 H 24.371 c -5.522,0 -10,4.477 -10,10 v 427.735 c 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 h 307.046 c 5.522,0 10,-4.477 10,-10 v -37.722 l 92.825,92.825 c 5.908,5.908 13.764,9.162 22.119,9.162 8.356,0 16.212,-3.254 22.12,-9.162 12.197,-12.196 12.197,-32.041 0.001,-44.237 z M 307.276,82.53 H 258.889 V 34.143 l 24.193,24.193 24.194,24.194 z m 14.141,313.847 v 31.358 H 34.371 V 20 h 204.517 v 72.53 c 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 h 72.529 v 95.662 l 0.009,0.014 c -12.214,-4.741 -25.275,-7.215 -38.499,-7.215 -58.61,0 -106.294,47.683 -106.294,106.293 0,58.61 47.684,106.293 106.294,106.293 13.224,0 26.285,-2.474 38.499,-7.215 l -0.009,0.015 z m 7.531,-26.086 c -0.848,0.536 -1.706,1.057 -2.574,1.563 -13.131,7.67 -28.154,11.724 -43.446,11.724 -47.583,0 -86.294,-38.711 -86.294,-86.293 0,-47.582 38.711,-86.293 86.294,-86.293 15.291,0 30.315,4.054 43.447,11.724 26.428,15.435 42.846,44.008 42.846,74.569 0,16.35 -4.595,32.264 -13.289,46.022 -6.835,10.818 -16.166,20.148 -26.984,26.984 z m 135.391,108.405 c -2.131,2.131 -4.964,3.304 -7.978,3.304 -3.014,0 -5.847,-1.173 -7.977,-3.304 l -98.706,-98.706 -0.008,-0.001 c 5.856,-4.74 11.221,-10.104 15.961,-15.96 l 0.001,0.008 98.707,98.707 c 4.398,4.398 4.398,11.554 0,15.952 z"></path> <path d="m 246.838,238.403 c -20.641,12.674 -32.964,34.686 -32.964,58.882 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 5.522,0 10,-4.477 10,-10 0,-17.19 8.759,-32.83 23.429,-41.838 4.707,-2.89 6.179,-9.048 3.289,-13.754 -2.89,-4.707 -9.048,-6.18 -13.754,-3.29 z"></path> <path d="m 317.708,237.624 c -10.52,-6.145 -22.547,-9.392 -34.781,-9.392 -5.522,0 -10,4.477 -10,10 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 8.693,0 17.232,2.304 24.693,6.662 1.586,0.926 3.321,1.367 5.034,1.367 3.438,0 6.785,-1.775 8.645,-4.958 2.786,-4.77 1.178,-10.894 -3.591,-13.679 z"></path> </g> </g></g></svg></div>
<br>
<button id = "btn">animate</button>
```

I already tried to use % in trasform-origin and use 0% and 100% in the keyframe as found in some quite similar questions.

Comment: can you add your html along with this code?

Comment: hey @bubesh, i added a snippet :)

Comment: done better now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that transform on SVG doesn't work if used via CSS in IE and that why the rotation animation doesn't work 
Found this SO link which explains it [CSS transform on SVG Elements IE9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298338/css-transform-on-svg-elements-ie9)

and also in IE site it was logged as bug https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811744/ie11-bug-with-implementation-of-css-transforms-in-svg

Comment: “That is annoying, but tolerable.”

Comment: I think i'll apply the workaround found on your first link. Many thanks

Comment: you can create that spinning circle with CSS instead of SVG and place the icon inside it and apply the animation, it should work like https://codepen.io/phliem/pen/vKQoBr

Comment: And how about animating the stroke-dashoffset attribute? It would not require transform!! i tryed but with no result :(.

Comment: hmm... i am not sure but can you send that code in jsfiddle

Comment: take a look to the next answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {
  $(".bg")[0].classList.toggle("rotate");
})
```

```css
@keyframes PDFgenerating {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset : 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset : 500;
  }
}
.bg circle {
  fill:white;
  stroke: blue;
}
.bg circle {
  -moz-transition : stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -o-transition  : stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  transition   : stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  stroke-dasharray : 290 !important;
}

.bg.rotate circle {
  -moz-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -o-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  transition: stroke-dasharray cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) .7s;
  -moz-animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite;
  animation: PDFgenerating linear 5s infinite;
  stroke-dasharray: 28 !important;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -ms-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myIcon" style = "width:100px"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" focusable="false"><g class="bg"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45.56" style="stroke-width:4.44;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0"></circle></g><g class="fg" transform="translate(50,50) scale(0.5) translate(-50,-50)"><g transform="matrix(0.19920319,0,0,0.19920319,2.5095651e-4,-1.38e-6)"> <g> <path d="m 478.482,448.601 -101.6,-101.599 c 8.089,-15.262 12.339,-32.29 12.339,-49.717 0,-35.689 -18.182,-69.164 -47.804,-88.743 V 92.53 c 0,-2.652 -1.054,-5.196 -2.929,-7.071 L 255.959,2.929 C 254.083,1.054 251.54,0 248.888,0 H 24.371 c -5.522,0 -10,4.477 -10,10 v 427.735 c 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 h 307.046 c 5.522,0 10,-4.477 10,-10 v -37.722 l 92.825,92.825 c 5.908,5.908 13.764,9.162 22.119,9.162 8.356,0 16.212,-3.254 22.12,-9.162 12.197,-12.196 12.197,-32.041 0.001,-44.237 z M 307.276,82.53 H 258.889 V 34.143 l 24.193,24.193 24.194,24.194 z m 14.141,313.847 v 31.358 H 34.371 V 20 h 204.517 v 72.53 c 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 h 72.529 v 95.662 l 0.009,0.014 c -12.214,-4.741 -25.275,-7.215 -38.499,-7.215 -58.61,0 -106.294,47.683 -106.294,106.293 0,58.61 47.684,106.293 106.294,106.293 13.224,0 26.285,-2.474 38.499,-7.215 l -0.009,0.015 z m 7.531,-26.086 c -0.848,0.536 -1.706,1.057 -2.574,1.563 -13.131,7.67 -28.154,11.724 -43.446,11.724 -47.583,0 -86.294,-38.711 -86.294,-86.293 0,-47.582 38.711,-86.293 86.294,-86.293 15.291,0 30.315,4.054 43.447,11.724 26.428,15.435 42.846,44.008 42.846,74.569 0,16.35 -4.595,32.264 -13.289,46.022 -6.835,10.818 -16.166,20.148 -26.984,26.984 z m 135.391,108.405 c -2.131,2.131 -4.964,3.304 -7.978,3.304 -3.014,0 -5.847,-1.173 -7.977,-3.304 l -98.706,-98.706 -0.008,-0.001 c 5.856,-4.74 11.221,-10.104 15.961,-15.96 l 0.001,0.008 98.707,98.707 c 4.398,4.398 4.398,11.554 0,15.952 z"></path> <path d="m 246.838,238.403 c -20.641,12.674 -32.964,34.686 -32.964,58.882 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 5.522,0 10,-4.477 10,-10 0,-17.19 8.759,-32.83 23.429,-41.838 4.707,-2.89 6.179,-9.048 3.289,-13.754 -2.89,-4.707 -9.048,-6.18 -13.754,-3.29 z"></path> <path d="m 317.708,237.624 c -10.52,-6.145 -22.547,-9.392 -34.781,-9.392 -5.522,0 -10,4.477 -10,10 0,5.523 4.478,10 10,10 8.693,0 17.232,2.304 24.693,6.662 1.586,0.926 3.321,1.367 5.034,1.367 3.438,0 6.785,-1.775 8.645,-4.958 2.786,-4.77 1.178,-10.894 -3.591,-13.679 z"></path> </g> </g></g></svg></div>
<br>
<button id = "btn">animate</button>
```

This could be an alternative without css transform, but still doesn't work on IE/Edge.

Comment: So this doesn't answer the question? Why post it then.